# How to change WordPress permalink settings without killing CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress

I'm not 100% sure if I'm framing this question correctly but here goes...

When first setting up Civi and WP, I remember setting permalinks as **/post-name** so that /civicrm pages worked correctly.

We've been redesigning the WP front-end and for content structure purposes we'd like to move permalinks to **/category/post-name** instead.

Is it possible to do this without killing CiviCRM page links?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My current permalink settings are just that (though it might have been set to that before we installed civi but I do not think so).
I do not think it would brake the site since civicrm is a page and not a post but I may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks Netzih, the only thing is that we are running are a plugin that also adds categories to pages....

Comment: Got it, so I'm not sure. Though I'm assuming you can just change the base page to /category/civicrm in civi settings and than it would be fine.